# sizeof vs strlen in long running programs

Tags: c

Which of these is faster and can be used in programs which runs 100s of times in a loop (for size of strings)?

`sizeof` - it is a macro and a compile time expression.

or

`strlen` - it's run time expression.

In my mind I want to avoid `strlen` as it's a function and calling it again and again might slow things down - Am I correct?

Comment: They don't do the same job.

Comment: @WeatherVane character size is `1` bye and hence `sizeof` can provide length of string?

Comment: You should look up "premature optimization".

Comment: No, `char str[20] = "abc";` has a size of 20 and length of 3.

Comment: And also what `sizeof` is.

Comment: @WeatherVane: So `sizeof(str)` = 20?

Comment: And `char str[] = "abc";` has a size of 4 but length of 3.

Comment: @ScottHunter not when `char str[20]` it is a function argument, that's something else (the size of a pointer).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Then why bring it up in a discussion about `sizeof` vs `strlen`?

Comment: @ScottHunter then what was the point of your question?

Comment: @WeatherVane edited the question.

Comment: The edit doesn't help. What case are you concerned about? Show the relevant code.

Comment: @Barmar Edited the question

Comment: @Barmar I don't have the code currently but I have to copy values using byte positions into `char []` - even if the file is blank - hence the short string is not a problem

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus So you want to read/write fixed length strings to a file?  That's wasn't made clear in the question.  Then `strlen` won't work in this case.  You have to use `sizeof` to get the size of the variable to read/write.

Comment: If you're copying from a file, why isn't it the case where the array can have a different size than the string length?

Comment: @dbush He said he's copying *from* the file.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus It's really hard to give a good answer when the question is so vague.

Comment: @Barmar I have written the code, can you please now look into it

Comment: `strlen()` won't work at all in your code. You're using the length of the destination array, it hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: You're not adding a null terminator to `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, etc. `strncpy()` won't do that automatically.

Comment: BTW, whenever you find yourself naming variables like `c1`, `c2`, etc. you should probably be using a dynamically-sized array rather than hard-coded variable names.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your help, I messed up even now by not posting the entire code. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These do **not** do the same thing.

`sizeof` is an operator which, in most cases, is evaluated at compile time.  It gives the size in bytes of a variable, including arrays and structs.  In contrast, `strlen` is a function which returns the length of the string passed to it.

For example:

```
char str[100] = "hello";
printf("size = %zu\n", sizeof str);   // prints 100
printf("len = %zu\n", strlen(str));   // prints 5
```

That being said, if you're looking to optimize something like this:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
    ...
}
```

You should do this instead:

```
int i;
int len = strlen(str);
for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: edited the question

Comment: You can also avoid getting the length in the first place. `for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are not string literals or arrays then `strlen` is your only choice. Either way, it will be fast—`strlen` is usually very heavily optimized.